# jhipster missing page and sort from url

Tags: jhipster

When creating a new page/ component I copied the generated code from the entity and inserted it into the controller. When I hit the loadall() the URL is missing page and sort. Example (?page=NaN&size=20&sort=undefined,desc&sort=id)

I have tried to see what I am missing and am just not seeing it.
What broke as the code is the same and works on the entity and not on the new component?